# ParrotOS install giving bad unsquash config error

Tags: linux, parrotsec, squashfs

I installed Parrot (5.0.1 Home edition, amd64) onto a USB stick using Rufus to use as a live boot on an old laptop I had lying around. I then decided to install Parrot onto the laptop harddrivehard drive itself with the onboard installer. I left all the install settings as default and selected the "Erase data" option, created a username/password, and started the install process.

It started as normal, wiped the drive, and created its' partitions. Then it threw up an error message:

```
Installation Failed
Bad Unsquash Configuration

The source filesystem "/run/live/medium/live/filesystem.squashfs" does not exist
```

Now, I am by no means a developer. I had intended this to be my learning tool into Linux type systems instead of Windows, which I'm used to. I've never heard of this error, and looking around on the internet and stack exchange I couldn't find a solution to a problem like this one that I thought I had a chance of fixing myself.

*Sidebar: It didn't throw up the error until after the drive was wiped. Windows is gone, and the laptop now won't boot without the usb stick in it, because there's no host OS anymore.*

I've tried rerunning the installer with custom partitions following a few guides online but that didn't change anything.

Can I salvage this? I assume it has to be a bad live install of Parrot, but I don't want to try anything else on my own.

Comment: "_I had intended this to be my learning tool into Linux type systems_" - in that case do not use Kali or ParrotSec. Go more a mainstream version that is actually user-friendly. For example Mint or Ubuntu. (Possibly Debian or Fedora.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Rufus, the image bootable usb that is created doesn't work. I assume that it isn't isohybrid compliant as mentioned in the docs of Parrot OS.

> The Parrot ISO uses the iso9660 format (also known as isohybrid). It is a special ISO format that contains not only the partition content, but also the partition table.

You can actually fix it by burning a new image to the USB using a burner that works with Parrot OS according to their docs, they suggest using Balena Etcher